# Error500 while testing a deployed cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm facing issues while trying to deploy my torchscript model on a google cloud function. The function itself successfully deployed, so I guess there were no errors within the code itself.
But when I tried testing the model using my local terminal using cURL command, I get this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

There is no traffic on this function either.

I used this code for the model:

```
import torch
from transformers import MobileBertTokenizer

from google.cloud import storage
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

def load_model_from_cloud_storage(bucket_name, model_filename):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(model_filename)

    # Download the model file to a temporary location
    temp_model_filename = "/tmp/" + model_filename
    blob.download_to_filename(temp_model_filename)

    # Load the TorchScript model
    model = torch.jit.load(temp_model_filename)

    return model

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_cloud_function():
    # Handle your Cloud Function logic
    bucket_name = "pytorchmodel1"
    model_filename = "model.pt"

    # Load the TorchScript model
    model = load_model_from_cloud_storage(bucket_name, model_filename)

    # Load the BERT tokenizer
    tokenizer = MobileBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/mobilebert-uncased')

    # Retrieve the messages from the request
    request_data = request.get_json()
    messages = request_data.get('messages', [])

    results = []
    for message in messages:
        # Tokenize the message
        inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            message,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=32,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        # Perform inference using the loaded model
        input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
        attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask']
        outputs = model(input_ids)
        probabilities = torch.softmax(outputs['logits'], dim=1).squeeze()

        # Get the probability of being a scam
        prob_scam = probabilities[1].item()

        results.append({
            'message': message,
            'probability_scam': prob_scam
        })

    return {
        'results': results
    }
```

My requirements.txt is:

```
torch==2.0.1
transformers==4.30.2
google-cloud-storage==1.44.0
flask==2.2.4
```

For testing on my local terminal, I was using this code:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"messages\": \"Our systems indicate your Social Security number has been involved in illegal activities. You must urgently visit https://example.gov/reportfraud/ to report any unauthorized usage. This is an URGENT situation.\"}" <my-function-url>
```

I checked the logs in my cloud function, and I found this:

> TypeError: my_cloud_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

How do I troubleshoot/resolve this issue?

Comment: You are coding the `function` incorrectly. See this [example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python#creating_a_function). A Cloud Function has a single entry point. Your code will work in Google Cloud Run, however.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried the link but I am still unable to identify the error. I tried to follow the steps in the link you sent, but I am still unable to recognize the issue. Thank you for your help though @JohnHanley